# java make backup without any storage

Tags: java, file, sorting, directory

I wanna to create backup to my files like the next:
the code will get the path and then
will create folders in same name to the new path
and the files will renamed as a new empty files in the new path

the problem i have the program will create everything in the same path
and i don't know how to sort it.
i hope you can help me

this is the code:-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new File("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads").mkdir();
        Loop(new File("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Downloads"));
    }
    public static void Loop(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                  new File("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads\\"+listFile[i].getName().toString()).mkdir();
                  Loop(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads\\"+listFile[i].getName().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are not advancing the directory in the code that creates the empty files or the directories.

The following code below should fix that

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new File("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads\\").mkdir();
        Loop(new File("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Downloads\\"));
    }
    public static void Loop(File dir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<listFile.length; i++) {
                String pathName = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                if (!pathName.equals("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads")) {
                    pathName = pathName.replace("C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Downloads\\", "C:\\Users\\Kurenai\\Desktop\\Downloads\\");
                }

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    new File(pathName + "\\" + listFile[i].getName()).mkdir();
                    Loop(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    new PrintWriter(pathName + "\\" + listFile[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works by taking the full path and replacing the backup directory with the file directory and ensuring this is the pathname that is used to create the directory/file.
See the variable String pathName as that is what does the work.